# Simple printf program doesn't work

Tags: c, printf

This program doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%а", 20.0);
}
```

I am compiling in C99. Expected output is 0x1.4p+4

Comment: please define `doesn't work`. Hint: use `%f`

Comment: It just prints %a. Please, I want hexadecimal output.

Comment: Are you compiling in C99 mode? The `%a` formatting specifier is new in C99. It prints the floating-point number in hexadecimal form.

Comment: You should probably post your compiler version and how you do the compilation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `а` is `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A (U+0430)`, but you have to use `LATIN SMALL LETTER A (U+0061)`: `a`.

If you're using a compiler that is able to check format strings like Clang or GCC, then compile with (at least) `-Wall` which includes `-Wformat` ([GCC Warning documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html))

```
5 : warning: unknown conversion type character 0xffffffd0 in format [-Wformat]
5 : warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

Comment: I found it helpful to go all the way and have a test program that yells at me whenever there is any non-ASCII-7 character in my sources, using proper escape sequences whenever I *need* non-ASCII-7. Stuff like this can drive you *insane*.

Answer (score 0):

Its really wired. When I copypaste your code it turns into `printf("%?", 20.0);`

You should check your character encoding.